# How to set text to Google Maps current location from another class

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I created a seperate activity to create a Google Map and set a marker on the users current location. In another fragment class, I'd like to set the text of a text view to the location from the map activity.

`CheckInFragment`

```
mLocation = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.checkin_location_text);
mLocation.setText();
```

`MapsActivity`

```
private void handleNewLocation(Location location){
    //SET THESE TWO VARIABLES TO THE TEXT vv
    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("Check In Location");

    mMap.addMarker(options); 
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    float zoomLevel = 16.0f;
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoomLevel));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to get the string value of location:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
try {
    List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),
                        location.getLongitude(), 1);

    String fullAddress = "";

    if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {

        if (addressList.get(0).getAddressLine(0) != null) {
            fullAddress += addressList.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + " ";
        }
        if (addressList.get(0).getSubAdminArea() != null) {
            fullAddress += addressList.get(0).getSubAdminArea() + " ";
        }

    } else {
        Log.d("Address:", "Couldn't find Address");
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then you can pass the `fullAddress` string value in a bundle when calling the your fragment class, something like:

```
YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("location_string", fullAddress);
fragment.setArguments(args);
```

Finally in onCreate method of your Fragment class fetch the string value as below:

```
if (getArguments() != null)
{
    _location = getArguments().getString("location_string");
}
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Hi Arun, Thanks for the answer! Quick question, does the GeoCoder code go into the MapActivity?

Comment: Yes, include GeoCoder in `handleNewLocation` method of your MapActivity.